# Ahlfors proof of a substitution for differentiating the integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, proof-explanation

This is in lemma 3, page 121 of Ahlfors Complex Analysis, 3rd edition. I cannot understand some of the analytic arguments he is breezing over. The lemma says that for $\varphi(\zeta)$ a continuous function on the arc $\gamma$, the function
$$F_n(z) = \int_\gamma\frac{\varphi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^n}d\zeta$$
is analytic in the regions defined by $\gamma$, and $F'_n = nF_{n+1}$. I understand the first part where we prove the continuity of $F_1$ and arrive at a formula
$$\frac{F_1(z) - F_1(z_0)}{z- z_0} = \int_\gamma \frac{\varphi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z_0)(\zeta - z)}d\zeta$$

He then claims this quantity on the right tends to $F_2(z_0)$, which isn't totally clear to me. Do we show this by relying on the continuity of what's inside the integral?

Next we take the inductive hypothesis $F'_{n-1}(z) = (n-1)F_n(z)$. We get this nice thing for $F_n(z)  - F_n(z_0)$.

$$\Big[ \int_\gamma \frac{\varphi d\zeta}{(\zeta - z)^{n-1}(\zeta - z_0)} - \int_\gamma \frac{\varphi d\zeta}{(\zeta - z_0)^n}\Big] + (z-z_0)\int_\gamma \frac{\varphi d\zeta}{(\zeta - z)^n(\zeta - z_0)}$$

He says 'by the induction hypothesis applied to $\frac{\varphi}{\zeta  - z_0}$ the first term tends to zero for $z \rightarrow z_0$'. Further he says we can divide this by $(z-z_0)$ and the first term will tend to a derivative. All of this is unclear to me, especially how he's using the inductive hypothesis. The last term looks like it will tend to $F_{n+1}(z_0)$ to me, but that's about it. How are these derivatives/continuity being shown? Can anyone show more details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\frac{d}{dz}\frac{\phi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n}} = n\frac{\phi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n + 1}}$. Let $\Omega$ be the region defined by $\gamma$. By differentiating under the integral sign, for any $z_0 \in \mathbb{\Omega}$,
$$F_n'(z_0) = \int_{\gamma}n\frac{\phi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n + 1}}\,d\zeta.$$
All we need to do is justify differentiating under the integral sign. As usual, this is done using the dominated convergence theorem. Fix $z_0 \in \mathbb{C}$. As usual, to use the dominated convergence theorem to justify the differentiation, it suffices to find a dominating function $g(\zeta) \in L^1(\gamma)$ such that $|n\frac{\phi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n + 1}}| \leq g(\zeta)$ for all $z$ in some chosen neighborhood of $z_0$ and all $\zeta \in \gamma$. Here $L^1(\gamma)$ uses the arclength measure on $\gamma$. Integral with respect to this measure is $\int_{\gamma} g(\zeta) ds(\zeta) = \int_{I}g(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|\,dt$. Pick a neighborhood $U$ of $z_0$ such that $d(U, \gamma) = C > 0$. Then for $z \in U$, $\zeta \in \gamma$,
$$|n\frac{\phi(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{n + 1}}| \leq n\frac{|\phi(\zeta)|}{C^{n + 1}}.$$
$|\phi(\zeta)|$ is in $L^1(\gamma)$ since $\phi$ is continuous on $\gamma$, and therefore bounded since $\gamma$ is compact. So the differentiation is justified.

Edit: Above is a situation when we had to compute a derivative of an integral. We have $g(z) = \int_{\gamma}f(z, \zeta)\,d\zeta$ defined for $z$ in a neighborhood of $z_0$. We want to show that
$$g'(z_0) = \int_{\gamma}\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z_0, \zeta)\,d\zeta.$$
Here we assume that $f$ is complex differentiable in $z$. To show this equality, we use difference quotients:
$$\frac{g(z_0 + h) - g(z_0)}{h} = \int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z_0 + h, \zeta) - f(z_0, \zeta)}{h}\,d\zeta = \int_{a}^{b}\frac{f(z_0 + h, \gamma(t)) - f(z_0, \gamma(t))}{h}\gamma'(t)\,dt.$$
Now we want to take limits as $h \to 0$ and bring the limit inside the integral on the right to get the desired result. We do this using dominated convergence. It suffices to get a bound of the form
$$|\frac{f(z_0 + h, \gamma(t)) - f(z_0, \gamma(t))}{h}\gamma'(t)| \leq H(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|\text{ with }\int_{a}^{b}H(\gamma(t))|\gamma'(t)|\,dt < \infty$$
for all $h$ in some disk $D_r(0)$ of our choice around $0$ and all $t \in (a, b)$. In other words, it suffices to find a bounding function $H \in L^1(\gamma)$ such that
$$|\frac{f(z_0 + h, \zeta) - f(z_0, \zeta)}{h}| \leq H(\zeta)\text{ for all }\zeta \in \gamma \text{ and } h \in D_r(0).$$
By the fundamental theorem of calculus, for any $h \in D_r(0)$,
$$|\frac{f(z_0 + h, \zeta) - f(z_0, \zeta)}{h}| \leq \sup_{z \in D_r(z_0)}|\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z, \zeta)|.$$
Thus it is enough to find $H \in L^1(\gamma)$ with $|\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}(z, \zeta)| \leq H(\zeta)$ for all $z \in D_r(z_0)$, $\zeta \in \gamma$.

Comment: Ahlfors proves this lemma explicitly to avoid justifying differentiating under the integral, and I don't know anything about the 'usual' arguments to prove this. I'm okay with understanding your proof instead of his since yours seems more general and helpful. What is the sequence of functions you're applying the DCT to? Is it $\frac{n \varphi(\zeta)}{(\zeta-z_m)^{n+1}}$ with $z_m \longrightarrow z_0$ and all $z_m \in U$? If so, how does this justify differentiation?

Comment: @Square I added an edit explaining exactly how the DCT is used here. Using DCT to justify interchange of derivative and integral is one of its major applications. However, here I think Alfhors was able to prove directly that the difference quotients converge uniformly to the derivative. In this case, the interchange of derivative and integration is elementary since uniform limits and integration commute.

Comment: This is much better, thank you. Just for one last clarification, when you say FTOC, do you mean mean value theorem? Are we then using the continuity of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ to say its bounded and thus $L^1$, like you did for $\varphi(\zeta)$ before the edit?

Comment: @Square We can't use the mean value theorem here because $z$ lives in a subset of the plane. But we can use the FTOC $f(z_0 + h) = f(z_0) + \int_{0}^{1}f'(z_0 + th)h\,dt$ instead and then use $|\int_{0}^{1}f'(z_0 + th)\,dt| \leq \int_{0}^{1}|f'(z_0 + th)|\,dt$.

Comment: @Square I didn't assume very much about $f$ to keep things general. This means that the bounding function $H(\zeta)$ need not exist (for example, the differentiated function might not even be integrable). In your problem you have to find $H$ and show that it is $L^1$ as I did before the edit. I found $H(\zeta) = n\frac{\phi(\zeta)}{C^{n + 1}}$.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your **first question**: yes, it looks like we are using continuity of the integrand. We can also make a more direct bounding argument. If $z_0\notin\gamma$ is in the interior of the region defined by $\gamma$, then we may find a neighborhood $N$ of $z_0$ which has nonzero (infimal) distance $D\ne 0$ from $\gamma$, and which therefore has the property that $$\Bigg|\frac{1}{(\zeta-z_0)(\zeta-z)}-\frac{1}{(\zeta-z_0)^2}\Bigg|=\Bigg|\frac{z-z_0}{(\zeta-z_0)^2(\zeta-z)}\Bigg|\leq \frac{|z-z_0|}{D^3}$$ for all $\zeta\in\gamma$ and $z\in N$.

Thus, from linearity of the integral and the triangle inequality, we may conclude that $$\Bigg|\frac{F_1(z)-F_1(z_0)}{z-z_0} - F_2(z_0)\Bigg|\leq \frac{|z-z_0|}{D^3}\int_\gamma \varphi(\zeta)d\zeta$$ and the RHS, which is an upper bound for the error, tends to zero as $z\to z_0$, since it is bounded by a constant times $|z-z_0|$. The desired result follows.